# getting namespaced attributes in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Oh, what frustration. The supposedly XHTML-complient CKEditor can't actually be served as `application/xhtml+xml`, so I have to switch to `text/html`. Suddenly my pages start breaking all over the place.

I serve a well-formed HTML5 document that uses namespaces---in particular, the "example" namespace. Some elements have the "example:fooBar" attribute, but I see now that Chrome when reading a document as `text/html` converts all attributes to lowercase---grrr!!!

So I change the attribute to "example:foobar" and try `element.getAttributeNS("http://example.com/ns", "foobar")`. No luck. So I investigate the DOM, and Chrome 17 shows a "localName" of `example:foobar`. Ack! How hard can namespaces be? Shouldn't Chrome be using a local name of `foobar`? That is, after all, the local name; `example` is the namespace prefix!

Is this is Chrome bug? Do all browsers do screwy things like this?